# Cannot load net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver in Tomcat - again

Tags: freebsd, jtds, tomcat8

Same error as [Cannot load net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911183/cannot-load-net-sourceforge-jtds-jdbc-driver-in-tomcat) but that solution does not work this time.  Just completed a Tomcat 8.0.9 to 8.0.12 update on a FreeBSD 10 server and am once again receiving that error even though the jtds jar is in the lib folder.  I've downloaded a fresh copy of jtds in case the old one got corrupted and I've also redeployed my WAR (just in case).  No change.  Obviously rolling back to Tomcat 8.0.9 is an option as a workaround, but I have some time to work on it and it's wise to try to stay up to date on server software...  Ideas on why I might be getting this error again and how to solve it?

```
22-Jul-2014 15:21:17.811 SEVERE [http-nio-443-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Ser
vlet.service() for servlet [base] in context with path [] threw exception
 com.sscorp.base.exception.SystemException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC drive
r class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'
        at com.sscorp.base.util.DBUtils.query(DBUtils.java:175)
        at com.sscorp.base.util.DBUtils.query(DBUtils.java:158)
        at com.sscorp.base.util.DBUtils.findEntitiesBy(DBUtils.java:324)
        at com.sscorp.base.util.DBUtils.findEntityBy(DBUtils.java:315)
        at com.sscorp.base.dao.common.UserDAO.findByUsernameAndPassword(UserDAO.java:50)
        at com.sscorp.base.web.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:2
22)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdb
c.Driver'
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1136)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
        at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.prepareConnection(QueryRunner.java:334)
        at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:483)
        at com.sscorp.base.util.DBUtils.query(DBUtils.java:172)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1130)
        ... 28 more
```

Comment: And what is the error message? The exception? The stacktrace? How do you load the driver?

Comment: The error is "Cannot load net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"  I'll edit in the full stacktrace.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding the code in our repository (it's an old program I haven't modified in a couple years, and the number of projects in our repository has absolutely exploded in the last couple of years).  I'll keep searching and post it up when I can find it.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` is pretty obvious, isn't it?

Comment: The error is obvious, but the reason is not.  The required file exists in the lib directory and functioned under 8.0.9, but fails under 8.0.12.  No code or config changes, just a Tomcat version upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After no luck with several days of work, some more software updates came out.  Applied them (didn't even reboot as they're not services/cached) and it magically works now.  Seemingly unrelated, it was curl and python that got updated.